# Trouble with Mobile xPage when accessing via Checkpoint SSL VPN

Tags: mobile, xpages, checkpoint

I have a fully functional mobile xPage application built using the extension library mobile controls (8.5.3 upgrade pack 1).   Works great when accessing the app (via iOS) from a wireless network inside the firewall.  Moving outside, the same app is not displaying at all when accessed through our Checkpoint SSL VPN portal.   I initially suspected a checkpoint setup issue but when I modified the xpage in question to contain only the basic "Hello World" text, it displayed just fine.  Seems that something with the extension library mobile controls   prohibits the xpage from displaying at all (just a plain blank screen) via the SSL VPN.  Anyone have experience in this area?

Comment: Can you access the mobile app from Chrome and inspect the traffic with Chrome Developer Tools (to see what comes thru and what doesn't)?

Comment: I'll give that a shot and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: It appears that the SSLVPN version is not rendering the right stylesheet.  I see the HTML tag as <html lang="en"> where as when I view the page inside our firewall directly I see <html lang="en" class="dj_webkit dj_chrome dj_contentbox mobile"> .  Further down I see the xPage XML coming through but without the same css styling that I see in the functional version.   Seems to relate to the missing stylesheet in the HTML tag.  Would I need to add that style sheet explicitly in the xPage resources?

Comment: As Stephan says, talk to the guys responsible for the VPN/proxy. There's probably nothing you can do on the XPages side.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [TCPMon](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/) to watch what exactly is happening on the device end. Then have a word with your proxy guys what type of filtering they have configured. Very often a VPN filters content to "protect" users from XSS or other threads. There is little you can do on your side if content filtering is active (short of calling the guys with the lot of tatoos)

Comment: Thanks Stephan, I wanted to make sure there wasn't a dev side fix to the problem before I went back to the proxy team.   It's a relatively new setup so perhaps they will be willing to tweak the filtering settings.